# Pandas datafram add column with line values depending on cumulative sum from existing column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I´m stupid and new to everything,

I want to create a new column with values that depends on the cumulative sum with a condition from an existing column and when the condition is reached the cumulative sum should start over from zero on the existing line.

For example, from this existing dataframe I want to create a new column that "tags" each line with the same tag depending on that the cumulative sum of the line with previous rows is less or equal to 80 (condition). When the condition is met the counter should start over from zero again.:

| Ops | Values |
| --- | --- |
| First | 20 |
| Second | 10 |
| Third | 35 |
| Fourth | 15 |
| Fith | 70 |
| Sixth | 15 |
| Seventh | 32 |
| Eighth | 32 |
| Ninth | 32 |
| ... | ... |

I want to acheive this:

| Ops | Values | New column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 20 | Stn 1 |
| Second | 10 | Stn 1 |
| Third | 35 | Stn 1 |
| Fourth | 15 | Stn 1 |
| Fith | 70 | Stn 2 |
| Sixth | 15 | Stn 3 |
| Seventh | 65 | Stn 3 |
| Eighth | 80 | Stn 4 |
| Ninth | 32 | Stn 5 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do this and I didn't find the answer somewhere else. Could someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can divide by `80` and round up to get group.

```py
df['New column'] = 'Stn ' + np.ceil(df['Values'].cumsum().div(80)).astype(int).astype(str)
```

```
print(df)

       Ops  Values New column
0    First      20      Stn 1
1   Second      10      Stn 1
2    Third      35      Stn 1
3   Fourth      15      Stn 1
4     Fith      70      Stn 2
5    Sixth      15      Stn 3
6  Seventh      65      Stn 3
7   Eighth      80      Stn 4
8    Ninth      32      Stn 5
```